# JavaScript - filter in loop, create duplicate

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to filter an array with another array in order to know if there are new people.

```
const people = [
    { "name": "jerry" },
    { "name": "tom" },
    { "name": "alex" }
]
const newList = [
    { "name": "bran" },
    { "name": "jerry" },
    { "name": "john" }
]

const new_people = []

for (const pp of people) {

    let result = newList.filter(newL => newL.name != pp.name)

    if (result) {
        new_people.push(result)
    }
}

console.log(new_people)
```

This is the result:

```
[
  [ { name: 'bran' }, { name: 'john' } ],
  [ { name: 'bran' }, { name: 'jerry' }, { name: 'john' } ],
  [ { name: 'bran' }, { name: 'jerry' }, { name: 'john' } ]
]
```

But I'm looking for:

```
[ { name: 'bran' }, { name: 'john' } ]
```

I would like to avoid the loop because it makes duplicate in the result but I don't know how I can't do it without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a temporary array of people name:

```
const peopleNames = people.map(pp => pp.name);
```

Then the **peopleNames** will be as follows:

```
['jerry', 'tom', 'alex']
```

Now filter the new people from the **newList**:

```
const newPeople = newList.filter(pp => !peopleNames.includes(pp.name));
```

The **newPeople** will be an array of objects that you are looking for.

```
[{name: 'bran'}, {name: 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const people = [
    { "name": "jerry" },
    { "name": "tom" },
    { "name": "alex" }
]
const newList = [
    { "name": "bran" },
    { "name": "jerry" },
    { "name": "john" }
]
const output = newList.filter(a => people.filter(x => x.name == a.name).length == 0);
console.log('By USing Filter', output);
//filter the newList and retain those object, which are not present in the people

//Way 2: By using some
//const output2 = newList.filter(a => !people.some(x => x.name == a.name));
//console.log('By Using Some', output2);
```

Comment: Thank you, way 2 is simple to understand. But for way 1, it is difficult to understand the following part: ".length == 0". I thought by removing ".length == 0" I would get [{ name: 'jerry' }] but I didn't

Comment: @GrowyTobe, If you want to use **Way 1** and expect to get the output i.e. present in both `[{name: 'jerry'}]` you can replace `.length == 0` with `.length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array`'s `reduce` method to get the desired result:

```
const new_people = newList.reduce((accVal, e) => 
    (people.map(p => p.name).includes(e.name)) 
    ? accVal  
    : accVal.concat({ "name": e.name } ), 
[ ] )
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong you use the conditional (ternary) operator in reduce method. Shouldn't accVal have the value of [{ name: 'jerry' }] as "jerry" is in both array?

Comment: Initially `accVal` will be an empty array (`[ ]`). So, when there is a match nothing happens. When there is no match the element from `newList` is added to the `accVal`. Hence the result will have the expected elements - `[ { name: 'bran' }, { name: 'john' } ]`.